# how to send variable data on the same page using PHP PDO?

Tags: php

im doing pagination for my table where there are around 1500 rows.

```
$numperpage = 50;
$countsql = $connect->prepare("select COUNT(id) from prana");
$countsql->execute();
$row = $countsql->fetch();
$numrecords = $row[0];
$numlinks = ceil($numrecords/$numperpage); 

$page = $_GET['start'];
if (!$page) $page = 0;
$start = $page * $numperpage;

echo "start is ".$start.'<br>';

if(isset($_POST["action"]))
{
 $query = "
  SELECT * FROM prana WHERE product_status = '1' limit $start,$numperpage";
```

```
echo $output;
 
 for ($i=0;$i<$numlinks;$i++)
 {
   $y = $i+1;
   echo '<a href="index.php?start='.$i.'"> '.$y.' </a>';
 }
```

from <a href="index.php?start='.$i.'"> im getting value of start in my url but for $page = $_GET['start'] it is showing Undefined array key start . and start variable stays at 0.

THIS IS MY REFERENCE :- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TI78ax23qZg
please help.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is the thing you are looking for, here is an working example and in details explanation of this example,

I have attached the code and Link for better understanding, have a look
have a nice day

https://www.myprogrammingtutorials.com/create-pagination-with-php-and-mysql.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pagination</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

        if (isset($_GET['pageno'])) {
            $pageno = $_GET['pageno'];
        } else {
            $pageno = 1;
        }
        $no_of_records_per_page = 10;
        $offset = ($pageno-1) * $no_of_records_per_page;

        $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            die();
        }

        $total_pages_sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$total_pages_sql);
        $total_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)[0];
        $total_pages = ceil($total_rows / $no_of_records_per_page);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page";
        $res_data = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_data)){
            //here goes the data
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li><a href="?pageno=1">First</a></li>
        <li class="<?php if($pageno <= 1){ echo 'disabled'; } ?>">
            <a href="<?php if($pageno <= 1){ echo '#'; } else { echo "?pageno=".($pageno - 1); } ?>">Prev</a>
        </li>
        <li class="<?php if($pageno >= $total_pages){ echo 'disabled'; } ?>">
            <a href="<?php if($pageno >= $total_pages){ echo '#'; } else { echo "?pageno=".($pageno + 1); } ?>">Next</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="?pageno=<?php echo $total_pages; ?>">Last</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i'm using PDO method not mysqli so this will not work in my code. anything else please?

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the warning, change your code from:

```
$page = $_GET['start'];
if (!$page) $page = 0;
```

Into:

```
$page = isset($_REQUEST['start']) ? $_REQUEST['start'] + 0 : 0;
```

> Where `$_REQUEST['start']` is used instead of `$_GET['start']` to ensure logic works, even if method was not `GET`.
>
> And the "+ 0" is to ensure it's numeric.

---

Also, `start` param is not set until one of links is clicked.

Comment: i tried your suggestions but it is still showing Undefined array key also im using PDO not mysql or mysqli

Comment: See Edit - retry with `isset(...)` and `$_REQUEST[...]` and ensure that everywhere `$page` is used instead of `$_GET['start']`